# ajax popup div form is submitting multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

In first jsp page

**Main.jsp**

```
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
 <div class="sharePost">
 </div>

<s:iterator var="msge" value="messageList">
    <div class="message" id="<s:property value="messageid"/>_<s:property  value="ReceivedById"/>">
        <s:property value="messageid"/>
 <span class="share">
          <a href="#" id="sharethis" title="share this">Share</a>
 </span>
 <span class="sharecount">
          <s:if test="%{totalShare>0}">
             <s:property value="totalShare"/>
          </s:if>
  </span>
</div>
</s:iterate>
<script>

        event.preventDefault();
        var msgid=$(this).parents('.message').attr('id');
        var msgid1=msgid.substring(0,msgid.lastIndexOf('_'));
        var receiverid= msgid.substring(msgid.lastIndexOf('_')+1);

        var dataString = 'messageid='+ msgid1+'&receivedById='+receiverid; 
        alert(dataString);
        if($('#'+msgid+' .sharecount').html(""))
        {
            $('#'+msgid+' .sharecount').html("0");
        }
        $shareNo= parseInt($('#'+msgid+' .sharecount').html(), 10);
        $shareNo++;
        $('#'+msgid+' .sharecount').html(""+$shareNo);
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",   
            url: "fetchSharePage", 
            dataType: "text html",
            data: dataString,   
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7");
                $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
                $(".sharePost").html(data);
               }   
        }); 

    }); 

</script>
```

This is my first jsp page where i want to fetch a share page containig message detail.
This page is properly fetching details of message in a shareIt.jsp
shareIt is a popup div.

**shareIt.jsp**

```
<div class="share-data">
    <h1>Share this to your profile
    </h1>

    <div id="messages_and_pages">
        <div id="messages" class="messages">
            <s:iterator var="msge" value="messageList">
                <div class="message" id="<s:property value="messageid"/>">
                    <s:property value="messageid"/>
                </div>
           <input type="hidden" value="<s:property  value="messageid"/>" 
                   id="message-id">
            <input type="hidden" value="<s:property  value="sentBy"/>" 
                   id="sent-by">
            <input type="hidden" value="<s:property  value="authorId"/>" 
                   id="author"> 
            </s:iterate>
 <div class="action-set">
        <input id="share-ok" type="submit"  value="Share">
        <input id="share-cancle" type="button"  value="Cancel">
</div>
```

```
<script>

        $(document).on('click', '#share-ok', function(event){

            var msgid=$("#message-id").val();
            var author=$("#author").val();
            var shareString = 'messageid='+ msgid+ '&authorId='+author;

            event.preventDefault();
            alert(shareString);

            $.ajax({   
                type: "POST",   
                url: "shareThisMessage", 
                dataType: "text html",
                data: shareString,   
                success: function(data) { 
                    $(".sharePost").html(data);
                    $(".share-data").hide(1000);
                    $(".sharePost").html("");

                }   
            }); 
        }); 
        $(document).on('click', '#share-cancle', function(event){ 
            hidePopup();  
        });
        function hidePopup() {
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
            $(".share-data").hide();
            $(".sharePost").html("");
        }
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 27) { 
                hidePopup(); 
            }
        });

    </script>
```

CSS used here are

```
.share-data{
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:600px;
    background:#6b6a63;
    margin-left: -304px;
    margin-top: -280px;
}
#backgroundPopup {
    z-index:4;
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#000000;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Code is working properly. Problem is while clicking on Share buttom

1 time form is submitting 1 time

then if I click on another messages share button  it is submitting 3 times

then if I click on another messages share button  it is submitting 7 times
and so on.

I am not getting why it is submitting multiple times.

Comment: Maybe I'm not right, but does th number of time the message is submitted is related to the message ID, can you check that?

Comment: NO It is not depending on message id or in authorid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling off before you call on

```
$(document).off('click', '#share-ok');
$(document).on('click', '#share-ok', function(event){ ....
```

I suspect your .on is being called multiple times, once for each time you've called shareit.jsp.

A few other problems. Assuming your iterator in shareit.jsp returns more than just one item, you will be creating multiple tags with the same id: message-id, sent-by, and author.  IDs must be unique.

Under `<s:property value="messageid"/>` in shareit.jsp, you have `<div>` which I think should be `</div>`.  Also, I don't see where you close these two tags:  `<div id="messages_and_pages">` and `<div id="messages" class="messages">`.

Comment: missing closing divs was my mistake

Comment: you might be correct  .on is being called multiple times(not sure, I am not getting how to test it)

Comment: $(document).off('click', '#share-ok'); by adding this code sharing is calling only once

Comment: Is there any other way that .on should call only once. above code is good but I want to know if is there any?

Comment: Ideally you only call .on once for the element.  Why is it called multiple times?  There is a function, .one, which is called at most once and then deletes itself - but that still may not work if the Share button isn't clicked.  You might want to .remove the popup instead of hiding it - that would remove any bound events.

Comment: I think so.  jQuery doc on .html - "Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content."  Or you could try .empty().